# Definition of the tangent bundle in Guillemin and Pollack

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

Given a manifold $X\subset R^N$, Guillemin and Pollack define its tangent bundle $T(X)$ as the subset of $X \times \mathbb{R}^N$ given by $$T(X)= \{(x,v) \in X \times \mathbb{R}^N : v \in T_x(X)\},$$ where $T_x(X)$ is the tangent spaces at $x$ on $X$.

But this definition seems contradictory to me: if $\dim X=k$, then $\dim T_x(X)=k$, and a vector $v$ cannot lie simultaneously in $\mathbb R^N$ and in the $k-$dimensional space $T_x(X)$ (maybe unless $k=N$). Please clarify this moment to me.

Comment: In this context the tangent space $T_x(X)$ is a subspace of the tangent space $T_x(\mathbb{R}^N)\cong \mathbb{R}^N$.